# Maven fails to parse POMs at jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have this simple maven project, containing a few common test tools.
It builds locally, but on jenkins I am getting this strange error (see below).

Other info:

- It builds locally with maven
- Settings are the same as all our other jenkins projects (very basic)
- Other jenkins builds work just fine
- I tried removing the /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools folder
- I tried deleting the build and giving it a new name
- The disk is not full
- I failed to find any useful infomation elsewhere regarding this specific problem.

**

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools (Is a directory) @ /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools**
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:128)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:109)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:136)
at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1254)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1058)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:909)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:920)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:652)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:506)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools (Is a directory) @ /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:261)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:157)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:120)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 1 problem was    encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools (Is a directory) @ /root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools
at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:116)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:259)
... 16 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Could you check whether there is permissions to read the settings file/access the dir etc?

Comment: Don't let your jenkins run under root better use a different user something like `jenkins`;-)...

Comment: Jenkins runs as root, so there should be access to the files.
- And yes I agree that jenkins should not run as root, and we will fix that, but it doesn't affect my current issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maven tries to read `/root/.jenkins/workspace/testtools` as its user settings file (normally under `/root/.m2/settings.xml`). Since this is a directory, it can't be read.

Check in your Job configuration under `Build -> Advanced... -> settings file` You seem to have selected `Settings in file system` without any value. Change this to "Use default maven setting" and you are good.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a pure rookie mistake.

Comment: Our Jenkins was configured with '.' as the value for Default settings provider. Fixing it here makes the error go away for any new projects.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem which was caused by [a bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42183) in the Jenkins Maven Plugin.  Updating to a version above 2.15.1 solved it for us.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check in your Project configuration in Jenkins under

```
Build -> Advanced... -> settings
```

here make everything default and you good to go

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem after I changed the build name and it included a space character. the 'execute shell' was using $WORKSPACE variable and that didn't work because of the space.

Answer (score -1):

This error could be triggered if the fully qualified path name for pom.xml is not used in the project configuration e.g 
`C:\Users\user1\workspace\WebdriverTest` is a not fully qualified. This is one is: `C:\Users\user1\workspace\WebdriverTest\pom.xml`
Take note of the `\pom.xml`