# Jenkins can't seem to build a java artifact. More information contained in a github gist [Pastebin]

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, ubuntu-14.04

Fresh Jenkins installed via Apt on Ubuntu 14.04 won't build maven artifact. It appears I can't seem to convince it to find the configuration

There was a lengthy amount of console output on one of the build attempts so I posted my attempts and their outputs on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chamunks/3d15bec008a6acaf8a22).

```
OTHER INFORMATION

Maven Configuration in Jenkins
http://i.imgur.com/LaHimRr.png

More Maven Configuration
http://i.imgur.com/geflDPA.png

JDK Configuration
http://i.imgur.com/UbD5LWQ.png

root@ci:/etc/maven# java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
root@ci:/etc/maven# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-44-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
root@ci:/etc/maven# git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

[Jenkins Project Job](http://ci.nixium.com/job/Network%20Utilities%20-%20Master%20Builds/)

Console Output

```
Started by user Robert
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Network Utilities - Master Builds/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/olivervscreeper/NetworkUtilities.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/olivervscreeper/NetworkUtilities.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/olivervscreeper/NetworkUtilities.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0776d5c1ad6594cdca17480295f11ab6b7629c62 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0776d5c1ad6594cdca17480295f11ab6b7629c62
 > git rev-list 0776d5c1ad6594cdca17480295f11ab6b7629c62 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf

    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:128)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:109)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1294)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1097)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:959)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:679)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf

    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:261)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:157)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:120)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /usr/share/maven/conf: /usr/share/maven/conf (Is a directory) @ /usr/share/maven/conf

    at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:116)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:259)
    ... 16 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

- -EDITS
  -Updated question title. 
  -Added information that was contained in the paste

Comment: I've revised this question and changed it about 90% hopefully removing my old question and replacing it with this one isn't going to break any rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven fails to parse POMs at jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449689/maven-fails-to-parse-poms-at-jenkins)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of that question.  As this issue appears to be maven not being found or runnable by Jenkins.  From what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response discovered in #Jenkins on irc.esper.net. That the answer was to just define specifically the file which was located in.

```
/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
```