# "Failed to parse poms" Jenkins maven build

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I am new to Jenkins and I am trying to integrate it with Cucumber and Maven ( so i can schedule automated scripts) but whenever I try to run my build I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/java" (in directory "C:\Users\rharrigan\Documents\TestingScripts\tcwebsitelinks"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:278)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:798)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
[CucumberReport] Preparing Cucumber Reports
[CucumberReport] Copied 0 json files from workspace "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CucumberTest" to reports directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CucumberTest\builds\9\cucumber-html-reports\.cache"
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: basedir C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CucumberTest\builds\9\cucumber-html-reports\.cache does not exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:879)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.findJsonFiles(CucumberReportPublisher.java:148)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:101)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:73)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1067)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Build step 'Cucumber reports' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The java programm can't be found see `Cannot run program "/bin/java"....CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`...Java is not correctly configured on Jenkins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven fails to parse POMs at jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449689/maven-fails-to-parse-poms-at-jenkins)