# Gradle Build Error in Jenkins - build.gradle: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not b

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build

When I'm trying to run a Gradle project on Jenkins,
Im facing the following error after my solution method becomes a build success.
Therefore the entire build is getting failed. But the same project is executing perfectly on local machine without any error. This particular error is only raised on Jenkins.

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   Total time: 47.936 secs
>   Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
>
> Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
>   Parsing POMs
>   ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectOne/build.gradle: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not b (position: START_DOCUMENT seen b... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1

Any idea about a method to solve it?

As for the Stack Reference on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449689/maven-fails-to-parse-poms-at-jenkins), I tried to ensure the *config properties* in the Jenkins on *Build > Advance* Settings according to the verified answer. But it didn't resolve the failure. Could be because it is specified to Maven instead of Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Jenkins job as a new **FreeStyle Job**. Other job types caused the issue.

The reason why I faced this concern was because the Jenkins job wasn't created as a FreeStyle Job in Jenkins. Therefore it is searching for the Pom though the gradle.build was given as the build file